# Is there a token for base url?

Tags: tokens

We are often caught by having links in Message Templates that work on live, but then incorrectly take us to the live site when testing on dev - which can result in confusion or worse, errors or incorrect conclusions.

Anyone know if there is such a token but it just isn't visible via the token selector?

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no token for base URL is available in civicrm. If you want to use base URL in templates, you can try this:

```
 // Declare $config;
 $config = & CRM_Core_Config::singleton();

 $baseUrl = $config->userFrameworkBaseURL;
```

This will gives you base URL and use variable "$baseUrl" in your template.

Another way is, you can create your custom token for base URL.Refer following link:
http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Customized+%28and+Custom%29+Tokens

Answer (score 2):

There is a JIRA ticket that seems related [here](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-11153) but no evidence of an actual resolution to it.

Comment: I heard back from that company who said Joeren was no longer there and didn't offer any other suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same requirement (moving email templates between test and production). So I created a small extension that adds a Site URL token. You can find it here https://lab.civicrm.org/kainuk/siteurl